# Clarity on the Notion of Branch: A Visual Consideration

Tags: complex-analysis

Below is an excerpt from a question in Gamelin's complex analysis textbook:

---

"Let $D = \mathbb{C}$ \ $(-\infty, 1]$, and consider the branch of $\sqrt{z^2 - 1}$ on $D$ that is positive on the interval $(1, \infty)$."

---

Could someone visually illustrate what is happening here? That is, the domain, the branch, the restrictions, etc.

Comment: Is $(-\infty, 1]$ a ray of points to be excluded from $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Yes.  The domain is the domain of the function.  The term domain is a connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$.  A branch is a particular inverse of a multivalued function.  For example, $\operatorname{Arg}$ is one branch of $\operatorname{arg}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt at visualization, produced using Maple.  This is the real part of $f(z)$.  Highest values are in red, lowest in purple.  Note that the real part is $0$ on the interval $[-1,1]$,  is positive on $[1,\infty)$, and negative on $(-\infty,-1]$.
(Well, we only see $-2$ to $2$, but you can take my word for it that it continues in this way to the left and right).

[image]

This is the imaginary part.

[image]

Note that the imaginary part is $0$ on $(-\infty, -1]$ and $[1,\infty)$, and has a jump
across the branch cut on $[-1,1]$.  The function turns out to be continuous on $(-\infty,-1)$ even though that was excluded from the domain.

Since Maple actually uses the principal branch of the square root, the formula I actually used was

$$ f(z) = \cases{i \sqrt{1 - z^2} & for $\text{Im}(z) > 0$\cr
                -i \sqrt{1 - z^2} & otherwise\cr } $$